# Spring-cloud-config Git SSH

Tags: git, spring-cloud-config

I have used these as examples:

```
'{"git": { "uri": "ssh://git@github.com/spring-cloud-services-samples/cook.git", "hostKey": "AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+...", "hostKeyAlgorithm": "ssh-rsa", "privateKey": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIJKQIB..."} }'
```

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_git_ssh_configuration_using_properties

I have finally gotten it to accept the hostKey but now it fails with:

```
Cannot clone or checkout repository] with root cause
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
```

The key works fine when SSHing or Git clone manually.

Comment: Did you add the public SSH key to a GitHub account with access to this repository?

Comment: Yes, I am able to git clone successfully from the server using the SSH key.

Comment: I was able to get it working but I had to also create and place the .ssh/config file with the correct info and I couldn't pass the SSH key file through property either.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue. You can create the ssh-keys in window machine with below mentioned command.

> Try this in command prompt not in git bash:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your email address here"
```

and try with git ssh configuration in bootstrap.properties file:

```
git@*************************************************configurations.git
```